# Eliminating character "X" in date column without ruining the format

Tags: r, date

If you look at the 'date' column, there's an X in front of all the dates I can't get rid of.

```
country
```

[Country, date, confirmed, deaths](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ozAA.png)

If I do this:

```
country$date<-gsub("X","",as.character(country$date))
```

[Fixed dates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lk4Ti.png)

but then I can't convert the date column to 'date' to 'chr'

```
country$date <- as.Date(country$date, "%m/%d/%y")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHhRJ.png)

I thought I'd be able to get rid of the X and just flip the 'chr' to 'date' but that seems to spit out N/A

Comment: Your data doesn't have slashes, but your format does. They have to match exactly: `as.Date("1.10.21", "%m.%d.%y")` . You could even do it without removing the `X` since it is a constant part of the date structure - `as.Date("X1.10.21", "X%m.%d.%y")`

Comment: Can you please edit your question to include your examples as text rather than as an images/screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

The date shows NA because your original date is formatted as `mm.dd.yy` i.e. the month, date and year are separated by full-stops (e.g. **X9.23.21**), rather than by slashes as you specified in your code.

You just have to amend your code from `"%m/%d/%y"` to `"%m.%d.%y"`.